# CSS prevent background-colors from combining in overlapping divs

Tags: html, css

Right now I have 2 divs overlapping each other. A parent, and a child. One div has the .dark attributes, another has the .sidedrawer attributes. When I overlap these two divs, the background-colors combine into a color I don't want. I want to prevent the colors from combining.

```
.dark {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    color: #ddd;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    --main-background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    --panel-background: #37374d;
    --modal-background: #37374d;
    --text: #ddd;
    --invert: invert(1);
    --btn-background: #f2f2f2;
    --modal-hover: #37374d;
    
}

.sidedrawer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 170px;
    left: -170px;
    background-color: #37374d;
    z-index:99;
}
```

When these two divs are positioned on top of each other, the background-color seems to combine into a much darker version of the color. Is there a way to have divs on top of each other without having the colors combine? This is just a general css question, not a question about specific scenarios.

Comment: If you use transparency (alpha other than 1 in rgba), you can expect the color to combine with whatever is behind it

Comment: so if I have a background-color in my <body> tag, does that mean and div under it will combine with the background-color of the highest parent?

Comment: If you only have one semi-transparent element and a body with a background-color, the result is combination of that. (`rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)` is not really a "pixel color", the actual pixel displayed like a combination of `rgb(0,0,0)` and *whatever is behind it when it's rendered*).
And if there are multiple semi-transparent objects behind it (not blocked by any opaque object behind it), then the actual color will be the combination of many things (basically, computed step by step depending on what happens to be behind each object at that moment). Order may matter.

Comment: I see,so if you use the opacity attribute it will do some form of multiplication or addition. That seems to be the reason that having 2 of the same background combines.

Comment: So could you say exactly what you do want? Do you want the one with opacity 0.87 to e the only color seen? It would help if you could show your HTML so we can see the structure - how those two divs are related.

Comment: I ended up doing something else as the future problems that could arise from overlapping the divs with different opacity seemed to be not worth the effort to deal with. I ended up going with something else. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you just need to set its opacity to 1 (which is equivalent to 100%).

```css
.dark {
    background-color: rgba(227, 61, 148, 1);
    color: #ddd;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.sidedrawer {
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #37374d;
    z-index:99;
}
```

```html
 <div class="dark">
  <div class="sidedrawer"></div>
 </div>
```

Or, if you want merge the colors, you can set the base with de opacity 1 and and the overlap with a smaller

```css
.dark {
    background-color: rgba(227, 61, 148, 1);
    color: #ddd;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.sidedrawer {
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(4, 59, 92, 0.5);
    z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<div class="dark">
  <div class="sidedrawer"></div>
</div>
```